# Can't build Darknet with CUDNN support

Tags: g++, opencv, cudnn

I`m trying to compile the sources from https://github.com/pjreddie/darknet using manjaro linux. But the build is having problems when I try to use the CUDNN switch.

```
g++  -DOPENCV -I/usr/include/opencv4/opencv2/ `pkg-config --cflags opencv`  -DGPU -I/usr/local/cuda/include/ -DCUDNN -Wall -Wfatal-errors -Wno-unused-result -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Ofast -DOPENCV -DGPU -DCUDNN -I/usr/local/cudnn/include -c ./src/http_stream.cpp -o obj/http_stream.o
Package opencv was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `opencv.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
Package 'opencv', required by 'virtual:world', not found
./src/http_stream.cpp:46:10: fatal error: opencv2/opencv.hpp: Arquivo ou diretório inexistente
 #include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Here is my make file.

```
GPU=1
CUDNN=1
CUDNN_HALF=0
OPENCV=1
AVX=0
OPENMP=0
LIBSO=0

# set GPU=1 and CUDNN=1 to speedup on GPU
# set CUDNN_HALF=1 to further speedup 3 x times (Mixed-precision using Tensor Cores) on GPU Tesla V100, Titan V, DGX-2
# set AVX=1 and OPENMP=1 to speedup on CPU (if error occurs then set AVX=0)

DEBUG=0

ARCH= -gencode arch=compute_30,code=sm_30 \
      -gencode arch=compute_35,code=sm_35 \
      -gencode arch=compute_50,code=[sm_50,compute_50] \
      -gencode arch=compute_52,code=[sm_52,compute_52] \
          -gencode arch=compute_61,code=[sm_61,compute_61]

OS := $(shell uname)

# Tesla V100
# ARCH= -gencode arch=compute_70,code=[sm_70,compute_70]

# GTX 1080, GTX 1070, GTX 1060, GTX 1050, GTX 1030, Titan Xp, Tesla P40, Tesla P4
ARCH= -gencode arch=compute_61,code=sm_61 -gencode arch=compute_61,code=compute_61

# GP100/Tesla P100 � DGX-1
# ARCH= -gencode arch=compute_60,code=sm_60

# For Jetson TX1, Tegra X1, DRIVE CX, DRIVE PX - uncomment:
# ARCH= -gencode arch=compute_53,code=[sm_53,compute_53]

# For Jetson Tx2 or Drive-PX2 uncomment:
# ARCH= -gencode arch=compute_62,code=[sm_62,compute_62]


VPATH=./src/
EXEC=darknet
OBJDIR=./obj/

ifeq ($(LIBSO), 1)
LIBNAMESO=darknet.so
APPNAMESO=uselib
endif

CC=gcc
CPP=g++
NVCC=nvcc 
OPTS=-Ofast
LDFLAGS= -lm -pthread 
COMMON= 
CFLAGS=-Wall -Wfatal-errors -Wno-unused-result -Wno-unknown-pragmas

ifeq ($(DEBUG), 1) 
OPTS= -O0 -g
else
ifeq ($(AVX), 1) 
CFLAGS+= -ffp-contract=fast -mavx -msse4.1 -msse4a
endif
endif

CFLAGS+=$(OPTS)

ifeq ($(OPENCV), 1) 
COMMON+= -DOPENCV -I/usr/include/opencv4/opencv2/
CFLAGS+= -DOPENCV
LDFLAGS+= `pkg-config --libs opencv` 
COMMON+= `pkg-config --cflags opencv` 
endif

ifeq ($(OPENMP), 1)
CFLAGS+= -fopenmp
LDFLAGS+= -lgomp
endif

ifeq ($(GPU), 1)
COMMON+= -DGPU -I/usr/local/cuda/include/
CFLAGS+= -DGPU
ifeq ($(OS),Darwin) #MAC
LDFLAGS+= -L/usr/local/cuda/lib -lcuda -lcudart -lcublas -lcurand
else
LDFLAGS+= -L/usr/local/cuda/lib64 -lcuda -lcudart -lcublas -lcurand
endif
endif

ifeq ($(CUDNN), 1)
COMMON+= -DCUDNN
ifeq ($(OS),Darwin) #MAC
CFLAGS+= -DCUDNN -I/usr/local/cuda/include
LDFLAGS+= -L/usr/local/cuda/lib -lcudnn
else
CFLAGS+= -DCUDNN -I/usr/local/cudnn/include
LDFLAGS+= -L/usr/local/cudnn/lib64 -lcudnn
endif
endif

ifeq ($(CUDNN_HALF), 1)
COMMON+= -DCUDNN_HALF
CFLAGS+= -DCUDNN_HALF
ARCH+= -gencode arch=compute_70,code=[sm_70,compute_70]
endif

OBJ=http_stream.o gemm.o utils.o cuda.o convolutional_layer.o list.o image.o activations.o im2col.o col2im.o blas.o crop_layer.o dropout_layer.o maxpool_layer.o softmax_layer.o data.o matrix.o network.o connected_layer.o cost_layer.o parser.o option_list.o darknet.o detection_layer.o captcha.o route_layer.o writing.o box.o nightmare.o normalization_layer.o avgpool_layer.o coco.o dice.o yolo.o detector.o layer.o compare.o classifier.o local_layer.o swag.o shortcut_layer.o activation_layer.o rnn_layer.o gru_layer.o rnn.o rnn_vid.o crnn_layer.o demo.o tag.o cifar.o go.o batchnorm_layer.o art.o region_layer.o reorg_layer.o reorg_old_layer.o super.o voxel.o tree.o yolo_layer.o upsample_layer.o
ifeq ($(GPU), 1) 
LDFLAGS+= -lstdc++ 
OBJ+=convolutional_kernels.o activation_kernels.o im2col_kernels.o col2im_kernels.o blas_kernels.o crop_layer_kernels.o dropout_layer_kernels.o maxpool_layer_kernels.o network_kernels.o avgpool_layer_kernels.o
endif

OBJS = $(addprefix $(OBJDIR), $(OBJ))
DEPS = $(wildcard src/*.h) Makefile

all: obj backup results $(EXEC) $(LIBNAMESO) $(APPNAMESO)

ifeq ($(LIBSO), 1) 
CFLAGS+= -fPIC

$(LIBNAMESO): $(OBJS) src/yolo_v2_class.hpp src/yolo_v2_class.cpp
        $(CPP) -shared -std=c++11 -fvisibility=hidden -DYOLODLL_EXPORTS $(COMMON) $(CFLAGS) $(OBJS) src/yolo_v2_class.cpp -o $@ $(LDFLAGS)

$(APPNAMESO): $(LIBNAMESO) src/yolo_v2_class.hpp src/yolo_console_dll.cpp
        $(CPP) -std=c++11 $(COMMON) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ src/yolo_console_dll.cpp $(LDFLAGS) -L ./ -l:$(LIBNAMESO)
endif

$(EXEC): $(OBJS)
        $(CPP) $(COMMON) $(CFLAGS) $^ -o $@ $(LDFLAGS)

$(OBJDIR)%.o: %.c $(DEPS)
        $(CC) $(COMMON) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

$(OBJDIR)%.o: %.cpp $(DEPS)
        $(CPP) $(COMMON) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

$(OBJDIR)%.o: %.cu $(DEPS)
        $(NVCC) $(ARCH) $(COMMON) --compiler-options "$(CFLAGS)" -c $< -o $@

obj:
        mkdir -p obj
backup:
        mkdir -p backup
results:
        mkdir -p results

.PHONY: clean

clean:
        rm -rf $(OBJS) $(EXEC) $(LIBNAMESO) $(APPNAMESO)
```

It seems something related with new gcc or opencv version but I`m not right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay it is solved and I report back in case anyone else stumbles upon it. The whole mess was due the following section:

```
LDFLAGS+= pkg-config --libs opencv -lstdc++
```

pkg-config could not figure it out so I had to manually export it:

```
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/opt/opencv3/lib/pkgconfig/
```

then it worked with this make file:

```
GPU=1
CUDNN=1
OPENCV=1
OPENMP=1
DEBUG=0

ARCH= -gencode arch=compute_61,code=[sm_61,sm_61] #\ This one is deprecated?

#     -gencode arch=compute_30,code=sm_30 \
#     -gencode arch=compute_35,code=sm_35 \
#      -gencode arch=compute_50,code=[sm_50,compute_50] \
 #     -gencode arch=compute_52,code=[sm_52,compute_52]

# This is what I use, uncomment if you know your arch and want to specify
# ARCH= -gencode arch=compute_52,code=compute_52

VPATH=./src/:./examples
SLIB=libdarknet.so
ALIB=libdarknet.a
EXEC=darknet
OBJDIR=./obj/

CC=gcc
CPP=g++
NVCC=nvcc 
AR=ar
ARFLAGS=rcs
OPTS=-Ofast
LDFLAGS= -lm -pthread 
COMMON= -Iinclude/ -Isrc/
CFLAGS=-Wall -Wno-unused-result -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wfatal-errors -fPIC

ifeq ($(OPENMP), 1) 
CFLAGS+= -fopenmp
endif

ifeq ($(DEBUG), 1) 
OPTS=-O0 -g
endif

CFLAGS+=$(OPTS)

ifeq ($(OPENCV), 1) 
COMMON+= -DOPENCV -I/opt/opencv3/include/opencv2
CFLAGS+= -DOPENCV
LDFLAGS+= `pkg-config --libs opencv` -lstdc++
COMMON+= `pkg-config --cflags opencv`  
endif

ifeq ($(GPU), 1) 
COMMON+= -DGPU -I/usr/local/cuda/include/
CFLAGS+= -DGPU
LDFLAGS+= -L/usr/local/cuda/lib64  -lcudart -lcublas -lcurand
endif

ifeq ($(CUDNN), 1) 
COMMON+= -DCUDNN 
CFLAGS+= -DCUDNN
LDFLAGS+= -lcudnn
endif

OBJ=gemm.o utils.o cuda.o deconvolutional_layer.o convolutional_layer.o list.o image.o activations.o im2col.o col2im.o blas.o crop_layer.o dropout_layer.o maxpool_layer.o softmax_layer.o data.o matrix.o network.o connected_layer.o cost_layer.o parser.o option_list.o detection_layer.o route_layer.o upsample_layer.o box.o normalization_layer.o avgpool_layer.o layer.o local_layer.o shortcut_layer.o logistic_layer.o activation_layer.o rnn_layer.o gru_layer.o crnn_layer.o demo.o batchnorm_layer.o region_layer.o reorg_layer.o tree.o  lstm_layer.o l2norm_layer.o yolo_layer.o iseg_layer.o image_opencv.o
EXECOBJA=captcha.o lsd.o super.o art.o tag.o cifar.o go.o rnn.o segmenter.o regressor.o classifier.o coco.o yolo.o detector.o nightmare.o instance-segmenter.o darknet.o
ifeq ($(GPU), 1) 
LDFLAGS+= -lstdc++ 
OBJ+=convolutional_kernels.o deconvolutional_kernels.o activation_kernels.o im2col_kernels.o col2im_kernels.o blas_kernels.o crop_layer_kernels.o dropout_layer_kernels.o maxpool_layer_kernels.o avgpool_layer_kernels.o
endif

EXECOBJ = $(addprefix $(OBJDIR), $(EXECOBJA))
OBJS = $(addprefix $(OBJDIR), $(OBJ))
DEPS = $(wildcard src/*.h) Makefile include/darknet.h

all: obj backup results $(SLIB) $(ALIB) $(EXEC)
#all: obj  results $(SLIB) $(ALIB) $(EXEC)


$(EXEC): $(EXECOBJ) $(ALIB)
        $(CC) $(COMMON) $(CFLAGS) $^ -o $@ $(LDFLAGS) $(ALIB)

$(ALIB): $(OBJS)
        $(AR) $(ARFLAGS) $@ $^

$(SLIB): $(OBJS)
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -shared $^ -o $@ $(LDFLAGS)

$(OBJDIR)%.o: %.cpp $(DEPS)
        $(CPP) $(COMMON) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

$(OBJDIR)%.o: %.c $(DEPS)
        $(CC) $(COMMON) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

$(OBJDIR)%.o: %.cu $(DEPS)
        $(NVCC) $(ARCH) $(COMMON) --compiler-options "$(CFLAGS)" -c $< -o $@

obj:
        mkdir -p obj
backup:
        mkdir -p backup
results:
        mkdir -p results

.PHONY: clean

clean:
        rm -rf $(OBJS) $(SLIB) $(ALIB) $(EXEC) $(EXECOBJ) $(OBJDIR)/*
```

Also relevant to look which versions of cudnn must be used along with each version of cuda: https://developer.nvidia.com/rdp/cudnn-archive

Answer (score -1):

Because darknet program files was updated. 'GPU=1' in Makefile cause core dump error.
I was compiled with previous version of Yolo v3.

My archive is here.
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Ki5wKZ25uY6KrRfebou8xicIBaGxaQxb

Comment: In fact your answer ir wrong. The problem was manjaerro not recognizing the load flags.